# MeshLab won't open this .pts file. Is just mentions that it fails to open

Tags: 3d, point-clouds, meshlab

Is anyone else getting this error from this file?

[This is a link to the file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E4IXOUSkznTT1X5MD1qvC7X2YJAeUix4/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: rename the file as XYZ or TXT and retry to load.

Rationale. The issue is that **PTS** is a not very well defined format.
Currently MeshLab associates to **PTS** a rather obscure *EXPE PTS point cloud format* that is not very used. However MeshLab also supports plain ascii point cloud files (e.g. just triples of xyz coords) as the **XYZ** format or the very flexible **TXT** format that allows you to explicitly define how is coded the point cloud.

Picture below shows the parameters used to load the file you linked using the **TXT** file (e.g. skip one row and load x y z separated by spaces)

[image]